# How effective is Meta Stack Overflow in improving the quality of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta

I thinking about companies like Facebook and Google which were pretty minimal in their early days in creating a forum that is open and accepting of discussions/improvements to their parent site.

Stack Overflow obviously has Meta Stack Overflow and I was curious to your take on how effective you feel Meta Stack Overflow has been in improving the quality of Stack Overflow.

And more generally, how important is it for companies in their earlier days to solicit feedback from their users.  Isn't their a lot of noise to sift through?

Comment: It diverts meta discussion away from the main site, like a flood control channel diverting floodwaters from a town. That's a big win by itself.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16557/is-the-purpose-of-meta-to-help-improve-the-stackoverflow-engine http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/meta-stuff-is-not-building-a-solution http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/why-are-you-on-meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27268/why-does-jeff-dislike-meta-so-much http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying

Comment: I don't believe this question belongs here. I would vote to move to metametastackoverflow if I had enough rep.

Comment: @Bringer note the text of the tagwiki for [meta-tag:meta] ...

Comment: @AakashM Ah, so it has been catered for. Now to see if there is a tag for discussion about the meta tag ...

Comment: check out the [status-completed] tag

Comment: Meta is an outstanding success. You have no idea how many other sites I've been on and wished they had a meta for easy reporting (and prompt fixing!) of bugs, as well as discussion about the site that wouldn't be welcome on the site itself.

Comment: @Bringer128, shortcut to the end of this line of thought: [the `[meta-meta-meta]` tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-meta-meta)